# In SELECT, correlated subquery in select to transform rowID into rowname

Tags: sql, subquery, oracle-sqldeveloper, correlated-subquery

How to combine these 2 sets of code?
Tables: geregistreerd `g`, instrument `i` and indeling `id`.

I want to display `g.voornaammuzikant`, `g.achternaammuzikant`, `i.naaminstrument`, `id.familie`.

Table `g` is linked with table `i` with `instrumentid` 
Table `i` is linked with table id with `indelingid`

--oefening 1:

```
SELECT TRIM(' ' FROM g.voornaammuzikant), TRIM(' ' FROM g.achternaammuzikant),
    (SELECT i.naaminstrument 
    from instrument i
    where i.instrumentid = g.instrumentid) as "naam instrument"
from geregistreerd g
order by g.voornaammuzikant;
```

--oefening 2:

```
SELECT i.naaminstrument, 
(SELECT id.familie
from indeling id 
where i.indelingid = id.indelingid) as "familie",

(SELECT id.onderfamilie
from indeling id 
where i.indelingid = id.indelingid) as "onderfamilie"


from instrument i
order by i.naaminstrument;
```

COMBINED

```
SELECT TRIM(' ' FROM g.voornaammuzikant), 
TRIM(' ' FROM g.achternaammuzikant),

(SELECT i.naaminstrument
        (SELECT id.familie
        from indeling id 
        where i.indelingid = id.indelingid) as "familie"
from instrument i
where i.instrumentid = g.instrumentid) as "naam instrument"  
from geregistreerd g
order by g.voornaammuzikant;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do things in a complicated way, if they can be simplified? What's wrong with a simple join? Something like this:

```
select g.voornaammuzikant, 
       g.achternaammuzikant, 
       i.naaminstrument, 
       id.familie
from geregistreerd g join instrument i on i.instrumentid = g.instrumentid
join indeling id on id.indelingid = i.indelingid
order by g.voornaammuzikant;
```

---

By the way, those `TRIM`s you posted don't look good. `SELECT TRIM(' ' FROM g.voornaammuzikant)` is certainly wrong; I don't know what you meant to say with that. Perhaps removing superfluous spaces from those values? If they exist, is - by any chance - that column's datatype `CHAR`? If so, consider switching to `VARCHAR2` because the former pads values with spaces up to the whole length of that column.